# how to store values in mongodb in hashed format using python

Tags: python, mongodb, restful-architecture, eve

I am developing a web API using EVE REST Framework it contains a table which holds password of the users. When i send a 'get' request to mongodb the password is displayed in visible format. Can anyone tell me how to store values in mongodb which is not in a readable format(hashed format).

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Why are you on the first place displaying the password  by a `GET` call , in `EVE` you can filter out the response that the user would be seeing on making `HTTP GET` calls on the `Endpoint`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the hashlib library in python. You can pick from whichever algorithms you like, using md5 will look something like this:

```
import hashlib
password = 'abc123'
hash_object = hashlib.md5(password.encode())
print(hash_object.hexdigest())
>>>
e99a18c428cb38d5f260853678922e03
```

See the docs also, https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html